# Quickly fill in quads?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, faces

I have a large set of quads ready to be made, but there are several of them and I want to know if there is a way of getting them filled in. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Does not work, because both sides are part of the same edge loop.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bridge edge loops* (<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>) will work provided the end edges that close the loop are not selected:

[image]

Comment: Grid Fill would work here, too. :)

Comment: @LeonCheung Good point. Feel free to add another answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You can select one of the end edges and hold down <kbd>F</kbd> with your cursor on the side of the edge towards which you want to fill:

[image]