# Subtract Only Overlapping Portions of Meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

**Background**

I am trying to model a very simple, two piece necklace. The "plate" is a simple mesh with roughly half of it cut away. The "text" is two letters in cursive. Ideally, the plate and the text are to be combined in a way such that the part of the plate that is filled in will have the first letter cut out of it, and the part of the plate with empty space will have the second letter floating in it.

Here are the plate and the text, side by side. [image: side].

I have been able to use Boolean Operations to extract the difference between these two meshes, satisfying the left hand hand side of the necklace (the cutout part).[image]

However, to see the effects of the cutout, I have to either remove the text or move the text mesh away (thus revealing the cutout but moving the "l" away from its desired position).

**Question**

Is there a way to perform some kind of difference operation / combination of operations where the "m" would be cutout of the plate while the "l" is left in place?

Thankyou for your time and effort.

Comment: In theory, you could use your mesh you used to cut out the area on the right, to cutout the 'm' from the text. Then you cutout the 'l' with the mesh. With the letters separated you could add (join [Ctrl] + [J]) the 'l' to the mesh and cutout the 'm' from the mesh. The reason why I didn't put this into an answer is, that the boolean-operator with text sometimes has problems.

Comment: @DrRiisTab - I think that this is the correct line of thinking, as I agree anyway. The trick is to first convert your Text to a mesh object `Alt+C`. If for some reason the Boolean operation fails on the second half, you could always do a knife project and check the `cut through` option in the tool shelf. Then remove the unwanted area. I recommend keeping a copy of all of your geometry in a separate layer to use as a template though, that way you don't have to lose anything just in case some operations fail to work out, as you intended.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to preform both operations at once from a single object? This would be pretty straightforward to accomplish either in multiple steps or with two or three separate objects. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'll let DrRiisTab answer the double boolean method, however I will demonstrate how to do this from the Knife Project method, as it will ultimately get you there, and you will be able to fall back to it, if for some reason the boolean operations don't quite work out for you. As time allows, I will circle back and edit this answer to give you the textual step by steps. Until then you should be able to follow the Screencast Keys with success.

[image: CreateProjectionKnifeProfile]

[image: ExtrudeTextRemoveDoublesBooleanDiffernce]

[image: KnifeProjectOperation]

Note: right at the transition, you will have a open mesh, that you may want to close up. I would recommend <kbd>W</kbd> >> <kbd>E</kbd>(`Bridge Edge Loops`), see [related link if you need help with the nature of `Bridge Edgeloops`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23318/quickly-fill-in-quads/23319#23319)

[image: FinalCleanup]

Comment: @BrianTracy - I saw [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50545/21718) and thought it could be helpful to you as well