# Scuplting numbers onto a 12 sided die.

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, faces, sculpting

[image]

How can I draw numbers onto the faces of my dodecahedron?

Comment: What is your question about ? Do you want to sculpt letters on the sides of the object ? Do you want them to be as image texture with each side drawn unique ? If sculpting then subdivide mesh with Multires which currently does nothing in modifiers stack for your object and sculpt, if texturing then it's not about sculpting.. Please provide more context about your final result

Comment: I just want to sculpt the numeral digits onto each face, 1..2..3...12, for each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the mesh and go into edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle).

Switch you selection mode to face (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> >> <kbd>F</kbd>).

Select which face you desire to work on.

Set your view normal to that surface (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>).

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> >> V to switch your manipulator so that it oriented to your view.

Select a vertex on that face and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> >> <kbd>U</kbd> to set your cursor to the active selection.

Go back into Object Mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle).

Ensure that the toolshelf at the left side of the screen is visible by ensuring that your mouse is hovering over the 3D view, then hit <kbd>T</kbd>.

Add a Text object by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> >> T.

Immediately look at the toolshelf toward the bottom half of the shelf, and check the **Align to View** checkbox.

Now scale, rotate and drag your text to where you want it in the views XY plane.

You can Then manipulate your text's extrusion, convert it to a mesh, and boolean difference it from your mesh like in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50389/subtract-only-overlapping-portions-of-meshes/50436#50436).

Then just repeat this for every side.

You can see a quick .gif animation of this process at the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-AIcsWABDIsM2NIazV6bENSWXc/view?usp=sharing)